# Ajax Autocomplete Freezing/Crashing Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement [Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery) and pass some additional parameters. The documentation shows how to do it, but the problem is, when I attempt to use the value of another field, it's crashing my browser.

```
$(function () {
'use strict';


 // Initialize ajax autocomplete:
 $('#school').autocomplete({
     serviceUrl: 'schools.php',
     params: { address_state: $('#address_state options:selected').val() },
     onSelect: function(suggestion) {
         $('input#school').val(suggestion.name);
         $('input#school-ceeb').val(suggestion.data);
     },
     onInvalidateSelection: function() {
         $('#selection-ajax').html('You selected: none');
     }
 });
});
```

If anyone has some suggestions, I would appreciate it. Preview version can be found at http://www.keuka.edu/pete/Inquiry using the state and high school name fields.

Comment: You need to make asynchronous calls with your ajax, by default it should be set to true however see here to check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You may also want to look into caching results to speed up the query

Comment: See [How to use](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#how-to-use) on the plugin's documentation page. Your service isn't returning the correct json.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Jason, that may have been while I was testing something. The JSON is returning correctly because the autocomplete works, but it's not passing the state param. It works perfectly if I replace address_state: $('#address_state options:selected').val() with address_state: 'NY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, in case someone else is trying to solve a similar problem one day...

`params: { address_state: function() { return $('#address_state :selected').val(); },  address_city: function() { return $('#address_city').val(); } },`